# Cómo puedo encontrar la key con más valores de un diccionario en Python, asimismo, la que menos valores tiene?

Tags: python, json, diccionarios

me he estado matando la cabeza con bucles pero no he dado con la solución, lo que sucede es que quiero encontrar la llave con más valores y la llave con menos valores de un diccionario es decir, si mi diccionario es este:

```
{
   "A":{
      "B","C","D"
   },
   "B":{
      "A","C"
   },
   "C":{
      "B"
   }
}
```

La llave con más valores es "A" por tener 3 y la que menos valor tiene es "C" por contener un solo valor.

Comment: Recuerda que es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Python te permite hacerlo en forma muy compacta:

```
llave = sorted([(len(dic[key]), key) for key in dic.keys()])
menor = llave[0][1]
mayor = llave[-1][1]
```

Desentrañemos esto. Primero tenemos una comprensión de lista

```
[(len(dic[key]), key) for key in dic.keys()]
```

Esta produce una lista de tuplas. Cada tupla lleva `(número_elementos, llave)`:

```
[(3, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (1, 'C')]
```

Como en la tupla está primero el número de elementos, si ordeno está lista de tuplas, se orderan en forma ascendente por ese número:

```
sorted([(len(dic[key]), key) for key in dic.keys()])
```

En realidad no necesitas formar la lista completa antes de llamar a `sorted()`. Podemos usar una *expresión generadora*, que genera los valores de la lista uno a uno y los entrega a `sorted()`. Es un poco más rápido y eficiente.

Con el resultado de `sorted()`, el primer item en la lista es la llave con menos elementos; y el último, el con más:

```
menor = llave[0][1]
mayor = llave[-1][1]
```

#### Demo

```
dic = {
   "A":{
      "B","C","D"
   },
   "B":{
      "A","C"
   },
   "C":{
      "B"
   }
}

print([(len(dic[key]), key) for key in dic.keys()])
llave = sorted((len(dic[key]), key) for key in dic.keys())
menor = llave[0][1]
mayor = llave[-1][1]
print(menor, mayor)
```

produce:

```
C A

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la ayuda. Funciona si mi key se ve así?:
"rutas": [
        [
            "A",
            "C"
        ],
        [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C"
        ]
    ]

Comment: @ItachiUchiha. Esa sería una nueva pregunta.