# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir la lista con más y menos valores que se encuentra dentro de una lista?

Tags: python, array, diccionarios

Es mi primera pregunta y espero de verdad que se entienda, lo que quiero es mostrar la lista con más valores y la que menos valores tenga, es decir, si tengo esto:

```
[['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C']]
```

Debo mostrar como la mayor la segunda y como menor la tercera.

Comment: Hola Oliver, bienvenido, Para que podamos ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/584359/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-encontrar-la-key-con-m%c3%a1s-valores-de-un-diccionario-en-python-asimism

Comment: Puedes ordenar usando la funcion Sorting que sale en esta web:
[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sort-list-according-length-elements/)
 y coger el primer elemento como el mas pequeño y el ultimo como el mas grande

Comment: Bienvenido Oliver, es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask], evita realizar la misma pregunta en varías ocasiones 
 :https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/584359/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-encontrar-la-key-con-m%c3%a1s-valores-de-un-diccionario-en-python-asimism saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yo lo resolvería de la siguiente manera:

```
lista1 = [['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C']]
```

Se crea una lista vacía llamada longitud que guardara la longitud(enteros) de cada lista que se encuentra dentro de lista1, la cual se recorre mediante el for

```
longitud = []
n = 0   
for x in lista1:
    n = len(x)
    longitud.append(n)
```

En la variable "a" se almacena el valor mínimo que contiene la lista "longitud"
y en la variable "b" se almacena el valor máximo mediante los métodos min y max

```
a = min(longitud)
b = max(longitud)
```

Por ultimo, a través del método index, recuperas la posición donde se encuentra la lista con menor numero de elementos, que sería de 1 elemento y que se encuentra en la posición 2, y la lista con el mayor numero de elementos que sería 3 y que se encuentra en la posición 1

```
l_menor = lista1[longitud.index(a)]
l_mayor = lista1[longitud.index(b)]

print(l_menor)
print(l_mayor)
```

Resultado:

```
['C']
['A', 'B', 'C']
```